# KnockoutJS: Access to observable Variable outside of an custom component

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I already searched a lot but cannot figure out how to handle my issue.
I created a custom component and the template is within a `<script type="text/html"></script>` Tag. Outside of this template I have a variable which I try to manipulate after doing something. This doesn't work, it's not defined. Is there any possibility to manipulate that observable?

My code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<customcomponent></customcomponent>
<script type="text/html" id="customcomponent-tpl">
    <span data-bind="text: foo">Foo</span>
    <span data-bind="text: bar">Bar</span>
</script>
<span data-bind="text: foobar">Foobar</span>
```

JS:

```
var customComponentViewModel = function() {
    this.foo = ko.observable();
    this.bar = ko.observable();
    this.foobar = ko.observable();

    this.foo('Foo!');
    this.bar('Bar!');
    this.foobar('Foo! Bar!');


    console.log(this.foo());
    console.log(this.bar());
    console.log(this.foobar());
};

// do another stuff...

/**
 * Register KO component
 */

ko.components.register('customcomponent', {
    viewModel: customComponentViewModel,
    template: {
        element: 'customcomponent-tpl'
    }
});

ko.applyBindings();
```

Many thanks in advance!

Matthias

Comment: Can you show the place where your variable is not defined?

Comment: But `foobar` isn't *in* your component. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: It says: ReferenceError: foobar is not defined.

Comment: Edited the code. I want to change the Text inside the <span data-bind="foobar"></span>

Comment: As I said, you cannot easily access stuff in the component from outside of the component. And the fact that you try indicates a design problem in your application. Maybe it's best if you explain what you are actually trying to achieve and set up a jsFiddle that outlines the problem.

Comment: Okay, for now, I just want to change any variable outside of a component. If this isn't working, is there another way? Via params or something else? Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u159jyn0/

Expected behaviour in the output would be: `Foo! Bar! Foo! Bar!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a view-model that is applied to the document at all, you only have a **component** view-model.

Try this:

```
var vm = { foobar: ko.observable('') };
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And in your component view-model:

```
ko.dataFor(document.body).foobar('Foo! Bar!');
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u159jyn0/2/)